# Is there a categorical way to see that $K_1(A)\twoheadrightarrow K_1(A/I)$ for a nilpotent ideal $I\subset A$?

Tags: category-theory, k-theory, algebraic-k-theory

Let $A$ ba a (not necessarily commutative) unital ring. The $K_1$ group of $A$ is defined as $K_1(A)=\pi_1((\mathrm{Proj}(A)^\simeq)^\mathrm{gp})$. Here $\mathrm{Proj}^\simeq$ is the core of the category of finitely generated projective left $A$-modules, which is a symmetric monoidal groupoid and is sent to a Picard groupoid by the group completion functor $(-)^\mathrm{gp}$, and $\pi_1$ means taking the automorphism group of an object.  A ring map $A\to B$ induces a morphism $K_1(A)\to K_1(B)$.

I am considering the following problem

> If $I\subset A$ is a nilpotent two-sided ideal, then $K_1(A)\to K_1(A/I)$ is surjective.

I can show that $\mathrm{Proj}(A)^\simeq\to\mathrm{Proj}(A/I)^\simeq$ is bijective on objects and surjective on their corresponding isomorphism groups. Also, the group completion $(-)^\mathrm{gp}$ is a left adjoint. Can I conclude from these facts that $K_1(A)\twoheadrightarrow K_1(A/I)$? I am not familiar with $2$-categorical stuffs, but these seem to me like a left-adjoint-preserves-epimorphism argument.

ps. The proof I know is more concrete. Note that there is an identification $K_1(A)\simeq GL(A)/E(A)$, where $GL(A)$ and $E(A)$ are respectively the colimits of $GL_n(A)$ (the group of $n$-by-$n$ invertible matrices) and $E_n(A)$ (the subgroup generated by $n$-by-$n$ elementary matrices, i.e. matrices with $1$'s on the diagonal and with one possible non-zero entry except the diagonal). Then the surjectivity follows easily from that we can lift an invertible matrix in $GL_n(A/I)$ to one in $GL_n(A)$.

Comment: @qualcuno Well, maybe--but at least as far as I have learned, $K_1$ is defined as in my question. The point is that,  $\mathsf{Proj}(A)^\simeq$ may not be a Picard groupoid, and if you take $\pi_1$ for this then you have to specify at which object you are taking the $\pi_1$. Also, since $\pi_1$ is already a group, I think we don't need to take group completion to it...

Comment: @qualcuno I know this definition may seem strange. I guess it will look more natural from the definition of the K-theory of an exact category: consider the additive category $\mathsf{Proj}(A)$ with its minimal exact structure. Then the $K$-theory space of $A$ is $K(A)\simeq |N(\mathsf{Proj}(A)^\simeq)|^\mathrm{gp}$, where $N$ is the nerve and $|\cdot|$ is the geometric realization. On the other hand, $K_1(A)$ is defined as $\pi_1 K(A)$, and for a groupoid, its $\pi_1$ at some object is the same as the $\pi_1$ of the geom realization of its nerve. So it is exactly what I wrote in the problem...

Comment: You are totally right, my bad. As for your $2$-categorical question, left-adjoints preserve colimits, hence cokernels, and thus they are right-exact. So the should preserve epis, as you say.

Comment: @qualcuno No worries! Also, thank you for the $2$-categorical part---at the moment I'm trying to learn some higher categories, and it is a bit stunning to me that these arguments are just like stuffs in $1$-categories!